# Do resources stay with you between levels?

Tags: dungeon-of-the-endless

If yes, do they stay as is? Or are there some special restrictions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your resources stay with you when you change floors, except for Dust. The resource gain per turn is reset, because you start with no modules on the new floor.